# pointer to member variable of struct

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

```
class Main
{
  Struct BranchSub
  {
    Sub()
    {
      subName[0] = '\0';
    }
    char subName[20];
  };

  struct MainSub
  {
  Sub sub[20];
  };
};
```

i want to have a method that will return pointer `subName` when `subName` matches with given text.
For example something like:

```
MainSub test;
if(strcmp(test.BranchSub[5].subName, "Hello") == 0);//return pointer to `test.Branchsub[5].subName`
```

is it possible??
or is there other way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: I suggest you using `std::string` instead of C arrays

Comment: it can be any function that returns pointer to char or pointer to char constant. however i also suggest you using `std::string` and for example returning a reference to the `std::string` object

Comment: c arrays? if you mean char arrays then the device where the code needs to be transferred does not support string, thats the prob

Comment: @Biplov13: If your environment does not support `std::string`, that means it does not support C++, as `std::string` has been integral to the language for over 15 years now. If it's not supported on your target, that's for a reason. Chose a different language. (C? Assembler?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to use `test.BranchSub[5].subName`.

For second part of your question, you should use `std::string`:

```
class Main
{
  struct BranchSub
  {
    std::string subName;
  };

  struct MainSub
  {
    BranchSub sub[20];
  };
};
```

And then

```
MainSub test;
if(test.sub[5].subName == "Hello")
```

is more clear.

You even can use `std::vector<BranchSub>` instead of `BranchSub sub[20]`.